# MVC 4.0 Controller cannot find seeded data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to seed data for an MVC 4 project using SQL server 4.0 as the database engine, using the Microsoft MVC music store tutorial as an example.  I have set up a seed and DB context models, but the controller is not able to find the data.  I have verified that the the database file is created in App_Data and verified that SetIntitializer is correctly set up in Application_Start.  Here is what I have for code:

Seed data:

```
namespace RationalMethodApp.Models
{
    public class StartData : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<RationalMethodEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(RationalMethodEntities context)
        {
            new List<Basin>
            {
                new Basin {
                    basinId = 1,                                    // attempting to force a key value, will remove
                    Name = "Replace me with a real basin",
                    Location = "In a real location",
                    drainageArea = 0.0M
                }
            }.ForEach(b => context.Basins.Add(b));
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index(int? bsnId)
        {
            if (bsnId == null)                    // here to force a key value, will change
                bsnId = 1;

            var basin = rmDb.Basins.Find(bsnId);

            return View(basin);
        }
```

The context class is:

```
namespace RationalMethodApp.Models
{
    public class RationalMethodEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Basin> Basins { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubArea> SubAreas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdfCurve> IdfCurves { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Analysis> Analyses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FlowSegment> FlowSegments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SheetFlowN> SheetFlowNs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RunoffCoefficient> RunoffCoefficients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StormFrequency> stormFrequencies { get; set; }
    }
```

}

The debugger tells me that the "basin" object is still null in the controller after the .Find.  This must be a simple, basic thing that I have overlooked, but all of the help I can find on-line assumes that the askers know what they are doing - not true in my case!  I have also checked the discussion at [Entity Framework database seed doesn't seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389839/entity-framework-database-seed-doesnt-seed)
but this does not seem to be the answer.  Please bear with a total noob question.

Comment: as bsnId is a nullable type, could it be that you have to call .Find(bsnId.Value)

Comment: Nice thought, but this does not seem to be the issue as the "basin" object is still null when the controller runs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the full code of you **seed**, so i can't really be sure, but you might be missing the **Context.Changes()**.

As well you wrote

```
public class StartData : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<RationalMethodEntities>
```

If you don't delete your database before the application start, it won't do anything as the db already exists.

You could use :

```
public class StartData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways <RationalMethodEntities>
```

to drop it every time you start or

```
public class StartData : DropCreateDatabaseAlways <DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges >
```

to drop db when Model changes (which is great for start of dev)

To debug: Drop your database, kill your application server (so it goes back to application start), breakpoint in your seed. Start Debug,  if it goes in seed, check that data is in it after SaveChange().

Comment: Do you mean context.SaveChanges(); ?  If so, yes I am using that.  I had not been using DropCreate...Always because I didn't want to have it recreate the database every time.  This brought to light that there are problems with the setup of the database structure related to the primary key vs. the foreign key.  Fixing this issue may resolve the question on this page.  Sorry for the confusion!