# Override Seed method in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an object Class :

```
 public  class Post
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Content { get; set; }
  }
```

and i implemented a class to override Seed method like this :

```
 public class MyCustomInitialize : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>
{
    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        context.Posts.Add(new Post() { Content = "This is a test", Id = 2, Title = "my subject" });
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE INDEX IX_title ON Blog (title)");
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

and in Program.cs :

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new  MyCustomInitialize());
```

but when i run my program, the record which i want to add to my DataBase ( with Title "my subject"), it didn't insert to my DB and the Index didn't create too! what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call SaveChanges on your DbContext.

Comment: In seed method base.Seed(context) will save the changes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389839/entity-framework-database-seed-doesnt-seed

Comment: i add SaveChange on my context.. but it doesn't work!!

Comment: So, just saw that this is a console app. Try calling Database.Initalize(true) after your Database.SetInitalizer call.

Answer (score 0):

The SetInitializer call should be in your global.asax in the Application_Start() event.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MyCustomInitialize());
}
```

EDIT: As amarano says in their answer the database has not been updated with the new 'Post' because you haven't called SaveChanges...

Which makes me wonder how are you inspecting whether the index has been applied?

Also you should call

```
Context.Entry(TheTrackedEntityYouWantToUpdate).Reload();
```

To update the local (in memory entity) after your ExecuteSqlCommand call.

Comment: It is a console application Not a web application